# How does a for loop over a file work in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this piece of code

```
f = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
```

lets just say the textfile.txt is something like this

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How does this work? How does it know where it is in the file? I understand that it is printing over and over but why doesn't it just print the whole file over and over. I don't see how f is a range. I also assume it knows to stop at EOF?

Comment: Files are [iterators.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) @close-voters: those are some seriously weak/wrong close reasons.

Comment: You might find this edifying: http://effbot.org/zone/python-for-statement.htm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `open()` returns a file object - i.e. `f` is a file object.
File objects are their own iterators, implementing the `next()` method, allowing them to be used in `for` loops as per your example. And yes, the iterator implementation knows to stop at EOF.
Have a look at the description here, under the `file.next()` method details:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

Comment: Do C and other languages do this the same way? Do they have hidden functions being called when running a loop with fgets() or something similar. Or is this something only some languages do? It just seems weird to have stuff going on that isn't specified.

Comment: Different languages will have different implementations, but there are really only 2 basic principles at work here - treating a file as a collection of lines; and looping/iteration. Looping is generally a primitive operation in most languages, while iteration is a state-machine construct that simplifies looping over collections. Treating a file as a collection of lines is a nice conceptual construct that then ties in with iteration to give you the ability to `for` through a file.